# How to reload Laravel @includes with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, model-view-controller

I've got a single page application inside of my larger application that will send data to the DB, and will also display that same table's data. Currently, I have AJAX dynamically sending the data. However, to get the data just inserted to appear in the table that I want it to, I have to refresh. I've been trying things all morning, but below is the current state of things.

The View:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--I took some stuff out to make it easier to look at -->
  </head>
  <body onresize="resizeRecalc()">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row header">
        <div class="col-12">
          <img src="{{ URL::asset('images/takeStatsLogo.png') }}" id="header-logo" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mainArea row">
        <div class="left col-8">
          <div onclick="playPause()" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <video id="gameFilm" src="{{ URL::asset('images/basketball.mp4') }}" preload="metadata"></video>
          </div>

          <div class="timebar">
            <span class="timeItem" id="timestamp"></span>
            <div onclick="changeVidTime()" onmousemove="moveLine(event)" onmouseout="REmoveLine()" id="outerBox"> <div id="progressBox"> <div id="placeMarker">
                </div></div></div>
            <span class="timeItem" id="duration-place"></span>
          </div>

          <!-- This is a key part -->
          <div id="statList">
              @include('partials.statList')
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="right" class="right col-4">
          <!--Checking if we should make the user select starters. If we have them, no need to do that...-->
          @if ($game->starters != null)
              @include('partials.areStarters')
          @else
              @include('partials.noStarters')
          @endif
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      //Add Stat Form
      //This part here will add the stats, but it won't refresh them!
      $('input#addStatButton').click( function() {
          $.post( '{{action("StatController@store")}}', $('form#new_stat').serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#statList').load('/take-stats/{{$game->id}}');
             },
             'json' // I expect a JSON response
          );
          clearStat();
      });
    </script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/takeStats/genJavascript.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/takeStats/videoJS.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/takeStats/dataJS.js') }}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller method:

```
public function loadStatList($id) {
    $userType = Auth::user()->user_type;
    if(Auth::check() && Game::where('id', '=', $id)->exists() && ($userType == 'statistician' || $userType == 'admin')) {
        $game = Game::find($id);
        $players = $game->team->users->where('user_type', 'player');
        $stats = Stat::orderBy('video_timestamp', 'desc')->where('game_id', $game->id)->get();
        $statMeta = Stat_Meta::all()->where('type', 'recorded');
        return view('partials.statList', compact('game', 'players', 'stats', 'statMeta'));
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
}
```

I might be missing something but I thought this would do what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You cannot do that. You have to rebuild the entire table with javascript using the ajax response data, or return the already rendered html in your ajax response.

Comment: How might I go about pre-rendering the html in the partial? That sounds much nicer to me than rebuilding the table with JS

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!Thank @Get Off My Lawn for giving me a bit of a hint that I couldn't just use the @include. I went ahead and figured out how to pre-render the HTML and then bring it in. It is actually not that hard. The idea here is to use a JQuery function to do an AJAX POST upon hitting submit, then use .done to get then new full webpage. After you have that (you can console.log it to see what you're working with at that point, it will be the entire webpage) you can just get the specific div you want to refresh from the .get you performed, and stick it in the same div. Here is the code:

HTML/@include:

```
<div id="statList">
   @include('partials.statList')
</div>
```

The AJAX/JQuery:

```
$('input#addStatButton').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{{action("StatController@store")}}',
      data: $('form#new_stat').serialize(),
    })
    .done(function(refresh) {
      clearStat();
      $.get('{{action("StatController@show", [$game->id])}}', function(data) {
        var newData = $("#statList" , data)
        $( "#statList" ).html( newData );
        //console.log(newData);
      });
    });
  });
```

I'M SO HAPPY Y'ALL!!!

Comment: Why don't you just use $.load or in your controller return the blade you need. This is a little messy

Comment: Use that instead of .done()? Sorry I really don't know anything about JQuery. More of a vanilla man myself.

Comment: I will provide an answer on how to propably return data or views with jquery and laravel.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed this is not an answer on your question but a simple explanation you asked in the comments. And it can help somebody else

## Laravel and JQuery

How powerfull :-)

First i will try to fit this as much as possible to your needs with the information your provided.

Secondly jquery contains some cool ass functions a lot of people don't know about.

As you described you have a single page website or something like that. That means you have 1 `route` to show the single page i suggest `/take-stats/{{$game->id}}`. 
In your controller and i use as example the `GameController` you have something like the following.

```php
class GameController
{

 public function __construct()
 {

 }

 //the single page view
 public function index()
 {
     //your singlepage logic here....

     return view('games.index'); //something like this?
 }

 public function create() //this is where you post to
 {
    //logic to store the game stats...

    //this is where you return a succes message or something.
    //lets return the index instead :-)

    //dont't return $this->index! use redirect to the route.
    return redirect()->route('the.route.to.your.index');
 }


}
```

As you see above, we return the single page in the post response. SSo when you post to the store method, and it succeeds it returns the index page.

Now the jquery.

```
$('input#addStatButton').on( function() {
   //this is where to do the post.
    $.post(`{{ route('to.your.store.route') }}`, $('form#new_stat').serialize(), (response) => {

      //clear the stats because the post is succeeded in here
      //also reload the content. The response contains the new html content

      //now what we can do is replace the whole content....
      //something like $(`html`).html('response);
      //or we get the content we need from the response and this is where jquery comes in handy. The response is simply a html response so jquery can create a new dom from it.

      let statsList = $(response).find(`#statslist`).html(); //create a dom element of the response.
      $(`#statslist`).html(statslist); //put the filtered html in the current list.
      //thats all :-)
    }).fail(() => {
      // a fail save. When the post fails it will come in here.
    }).always(() => {
      clearStats(); 
      //this is called always even when it fails. You can clear the stats or something in here.
    });

});
```

A short description :

- Onclick post button, post to `post.route`
- Controller method does logic and returns as success the index url.
- jquery parses the html response and replaces the original content.
- done.

I hope this helps you or somebody else. When using a structure like above this code is simply cleaner and faster for it only executes one request.